# $geoIntersect and Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to use `$geoIntersect` with Meteor, but getting an error:

> MongoError: Malformed geo query: { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: {
>   type: "Point", coordinates: [ { lng: "34.8933452", lat: "31.9444389" }
>   ] } } }

Is `$geoIntersect` supported by Meteor 1.0 mongoDB driver?

this is the code i am using inside `Meteor.publish`:

```
Collection.find({
        polygons: { 
            $geoIntersects: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: location
                }
            }
        }
    }).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround:

There is a package in meteor that you can use. It is called [geojson-utils](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/180586a115a24de1e4a0068c3a784a678c691539/packages/geojson-utils/geojson-utils.js).
It has a method that does what you are looking for: `pointInPolygon` that look for an intersection between one point and a polygon.This can be a starting point.